# chrome : unable to read local files by using `-allow-file-access-from-files `

Tags: google-chrome, browser

### Introduction

Honestry,I'm not native English user,so my English is not better.
If you have any question, ask me by comment.

#### what I wanna do

As a premise,when you try to access local files by web site link,IE or FireFox can access( by simple setting) ,but Chrome can't access for their security poricy.

I found the ways to do this, like below:

1. add `--allow-file-access-from-files` option when you execute chrome.exe
2. build a local server like nginx or Apache HTTP Server,which meditate to access local data
3. Use chrome extention[Enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=ja)

Due to business restrictions,I should resolve this problem by method 1. but I can't enable loacl data link though I set option correctly.

I googled why I can't,but I couldn't find why it won't work.
(In the first place,I can't even find Google official description of `--allow-file-access-from-files`.How predecessors find that method ... )
While searching、I found person who have the same question、[Google Forum](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10926460?hl=en).
I'm convinced that this is not my simple miss,but more deep problem,so I decided to make this question.

#### what I tried

- I rebooted computer,killed all process related to chrome,then change directory where contains chrome executable file,and execute `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`
- I rebooted computer,killed all process related to chrome 、create shortcut on my Desktop ,which destination is `"/path/to/chrome/chrome.exe"--allow-file-access-from-files`

  After execute chrome,I checked chrome boot option to access`chrome://version/`.Both method, I could boot chrome by add `--allow-file-access-from-files` option,but can't achieve first purpose to access local file access.

#### what I wanna know

- lacking or similar to `--allow-file-access-from-files`option、
  (solution similar to method 2 or method 3,like "Give up option solution,and use nginx as local server" is unnecessary)
- or other solution

Additionary,if you know below info,please teach me.
- Google official documentation which descriptions`allow-file-access-from-files`
  ( Indended to Oracle official Javadoc of Java.)

#### Using Tool

Chrome Version : 78.0.3904.87
 OS     : WIndows 7 SP1

Comment: This issue persists even in Chrome 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable) using localhost:// vs file:// also fails.